# In OpenAPI 3 how do I use the discriminator column to map to a list of objects?

Tags: swagger, openapi, jsonschema

I have a response that looks like this:

```
{
  resources: [ { arbitraryObject} ]
}
```

So I have an `arbitraryObject` that I want defined in the responses section for an endpoint:

For my openapi 3.0 schema, use the `#/components/schemas/Resources` to discriminate a list of cats for the `/cats` endpoint. Here is my schema so far:

```
paths:
  /cats:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Gets all the cats"
          content:
            application/json:
              # use the discriminator column here to get a list of cats using the $ref: "#/components/schemas/Resources"
      
components:
  schemas:
    Resources:
      type: object
      properties:
        resources:
          type: array
          items:
            properties:
              objectType:
                type: string
          discriminator:
            propertyName: objectType
    Cat:
      type: object
      properties:
        objectType:
          type: string
          default: "Cat"
          example: "Cat"
    Dog:
      type: object
      properties:
        objectType:
          type: string
          default: "Dog"
          example: "Dog"
```

I've asked ChatGPT and it wants me to do define a list of cats like this:

```
    Cat:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Resources'
        - properties:
            objectType:
              type: string
              default: "Cat"
              example: "Cat"
```

But this requires me to create a new schema for every list of `Cat`, `Dog`, etc., so I'd have to create a `DogList`, `CatList`, etc., as well as the individual `Cat` and `Dog`, and this is just not practical.

I want to be able to re-use `Responses`, `Cat`, and `Dog` to create a single `Cat` and `Dog` and list of `Cat`s and `Dog`s.

Comment: Give an example payload of what you need and it may be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how this is going to work this way.

Reason: The `objectType` data field is bound to each individual object (list item). So for the `/cats` endpoint, a list of dogs or a mixed list of both cats and dogs would also be valid against the schema unless you explicitly have the `objectType` as a visible data field in the schema on the list level (rather than on the level of the list items level).

I think it would be a better design to explicitly bind the `objectType` to the entire list like this:

```
{
    "objectType": <string>,
    "resources": [ { "objectName": <object> } ]
}
```

This is of course different from your response example - is it an option for you to change this?